# Trouble with dates: TO_DATE()

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to audit some data to look for where the fiscal year of the **report_name** field doesn't match the **report_date** field.

Table: **transactions**

Fields: 
**report_name** (always ends in last two digits of the current fiscal year.  *e.g.* "transactions15" for fiscal year 2015)

**report_date** supposed to be a date within a particular fiscal year.

Our fiscal year runs from July 1 through June 30.

Here's what I have thus far:

```
SELECT report_name, report_date
FROM reports
WHERE report_date 
BETWEEN 
  TO_DATE('01-JUL-' || (SUBSTR(report_name,-2) - 1),'DD-MON-YY')
AND
  TO_DATE('30-JUN-' || (SUBSTR(report_name,-2)),'DD-MON-YY')
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error:

ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0.

I'm thinking that SUBSTR(report_name,-2) must be the problem?  However, I'm able to display it with no error to the query, so I'm confused.

Comment: Your conversion [works for the report name you gave](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/11339). Maybe you have names that do not match that pattern? Is report_date actually a date column, not a string?

Comment: Specifically, do you have a report name ending in `00`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is where you have the -1 to decrement the year. If you have  report name that ends with `00`, e.g. `transaction00`, you end up with the concatenated year as -1. You effectively then do:

```
select to_date('01-JUL--1', 'DD-MON-YY') from dual;
```

which also gets:

```
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
```

You can avoid that by using the original last two digits, and go back a year using another mechanism, like `add_months()`:

```
SELECT report_name, report_date
FROM reports
WHERE report_date 
BETWEEN 
  ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE('01-JUL-' || (SUBSTR(report_name,-2)),'DD-MON-RR'), -1)
AND
  TO_DATE('30-JUN-' || (SUBSTR(report_name,-2)),'DD-MON-RR')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/9eecb7d/11348) showing the conversion works now.

I've changed the format model from YY to RR, on the basis that if you have records from 2000 you may have them from 1999 or earlier, and with YY value '99' would be seen as 2099 rather than 1999.

Using month names or abbreviations is NLS-language dependent, so it's safer to use month numbers; or you can override the date language as part of the query but that's more typing.

Also note that `between` is inclusive, but only up to midnight on June 30th. If you have other times later that day they will be missed.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation and for correctly predicting that I had reports from 2000!  I have a working report and a better understanding as to how to pull the correct records.

Answer (score 2):

Better change your logic:

```
WHERE report_name NOT LIKE '%' || TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(report_date,-6), 'yy')
```